# Ext store retrieving data server side from a store filled manually

Tags: ext.net

I created 2 store, one that load data from database, and the other is empty, with 2 grids. I can can drag and drop data from grid 1 to grid 2, so the store 2 will contain data.

What is the best way to retrieve all the data that are in the store 2 from code-behind using C#?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following Ext.NET example can help. The sample demonstrates moving data between two GridPanel/Store Components, then submitting the results of the second GridPanel/Store.

See http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Miscellaneous/Two_Grids/

Answer (score 0):

I think, unfortunately, you can't get in code behind values from Grid or Store when use submit form or calling DurectEvent. This data is not submitted. The reason is to minify request, because if your form will contain many stores in some time they will submit too many unuseful data. Maybe solution exists but I don't know it.

Of course if you want some logic like in this example you can use it http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/WebService_Connections/StoreEvents/. But in most situations you need more simple solution. Just getting records ids in store in one string that will be sended to server. Example:

```
function getStoreValues(store) {
    var a = [];
    store.each(function (r) { a.push(r.id); })
    return a.join(',')
}
```

Full example you will find here: http://pastebin.com/pgSfgPt3

Answer (score 0):

On you client side

```
<ext:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save" Disabled="true">
<DirectEvents>
    <Click OnEvent="Save">
        <ExtraParams>
            <ext:Parameter 
                Name="items" 
                Value="#{MultiSelect1}.getValues(true)" 
                Mode="Raw"
                Encode="true" />
        </ExtraParams>
    </Click>
</DirectEvents>
</ext:Button>
```

On your server side

```
protected void Save(object sender, DirectEventArgs e) {
var items = e.ExtraParams["items"];
var selectedCountries = JSON.Deserialize<ListItem[]>(items);

//you deserializa all your data in ListItem, since I use a multi select. With GridPanels, you have to use the object.
return selectedCountries.Select(item => Convert.ToInt64(item.Value)).ToList();
}
```